# Why does applicative work default only for Maybe

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

I am trying to understand why do applicative functors work by default (no implementation needed)  for some functors like `Maybe` but for others don't:

Example:
`Just (+3) <*> (Just 3)` works fine "out of the box"- > `6`
`Left (+3) <*> Left 3` does not work 
`Just (+3) <*> Left 4` does not work even if i declare an `Either Int Int`.

I assume in 99% of cases when dealing with pairs of : `(f (a->b) , f a)` you must implement the desired behaviour yourself (**Cartesian Product**  `(f (a->b)) X (f a)` ) and the first example is just something simple out of the box.

**Example**
In the case of `(Maybe (a->b) , Either c d)` we would need to cover all 4 cases:
`Just - Left
 Just - Right
 Nothing - Left
 Nothing -Right`
Am i right in this assumption ?

Comment: `Right (+3) <*> Right 3` works. `Left` doesn't contain the type that the functor operates on. Furthermore, `Just (+3)` and `Left 4` are completely incompatible types.

Comment: So the the functor that contains the function has to be the same type as the functor that has the value ?

Comment: Right.  More generally, when substituting a concrete type for a type variable (`f`, `a`, `b`), all occurrences of the variable get replaced with the same value.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Yes, precisely. You can use `<*>` to combine `Either String (Int -> Bool)` and `Either String Int` into a `Etiher String Bool`. The `Either String` part must be the same: it's the same functor that is it used for the two arguments and the result type. Indeed, `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` uses the same applicative functor `f` three times (e.g. `f = Either String`).

Comment: Look at the type for `<*>`: `Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. The same applicative functor is used throughout. What did you expect the result of `Just (+3) <*> Left 4` to be, `Just 7` or `Left 7`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Applicative` instance for `Either` is defined as:

```
instance Applicative (Either e) where ...
```

given the type of `(<*>)` is `Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` for `Either` that is:

```
Either e (a -> b) -> Either e a -> Either e b
```

The type of `Left` is `e -> Either e a` so the type of `Left (+3)` is

```
Num a => Either (a -> a) b
```

and the type of `Left 3` is:

```
Num a => Either a b
```

which leads to the type for `Left (+3) <*> Left 3` as `(Num a, Num (a -> a)) => Either (a -> a) b` which is unlikely to be what you intended.

Since it's the type `b` which contains the function and value to operate on, using the `Right` constructor does work:

```
Right (+3) <*> Right 3
=> Right 6
```

Comment: There's a potential for confusion where you write "does not match the required type".  These types do unify, as `Num n => Either (n -> n) (a -> b)` even though the Applicative instance doesn't do what the OP expected.

Comment: Not only that, but `Left (+3) <*> Left 3` is an error because `3` and `(+3)` don't have the same type (unless you declare a `Num` instance for something like `(Num a) => a -> a`)